# How to get network usages/quotas using Azure SDK for Golang?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-go

I'm trying to get information about network usages and quota using Azure SDK for Golang and receive the same result as executing the following CLI command:

```
% az network list-usages  --location centralus --out table
Name                                                               CurrentValue    Limit
-----------------------------------------------------------------  --------------  ----------
Virtual Networks                                                   3               1000
(...)
```

My implementation (I also tried to use `NewListPager` instead of `Get` method, but the result is similar):

```
import "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/quota/armquota" 
// (...)

    subscriptionID := "<MY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>"
    factory, err := armquota.NewClientFactory(creds, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    quotaSvc, err := factory.NewClient()
    usagesSvc, err := factory.NewUsagesClient()


    quotaResult, err := quotaSvc.Get(ctx, "VirtualNetworks", "subscriptions/"+subscriptionID+"/providers/Microsoft.Network/locations/centralus", nil)
    if err == nil {
        quotaJson, err := quotaResult.MarshalJSON()
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Println("Quota result=", string(quotaJson), ", name=", *quotaResult.Name)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Cannot marshal quota json")
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Cannot get quota")
    }

    usageResult, err := usagesSvc.Get(ctx, "VirtualNetworks", "subscriptions/"+subscriptionID+"/providers/Microsoft.Network/locations/centralus", nil)
    if err == nil {
        usagesJson, err := usageResult.MarshalJSON()
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Println("Usages result=", string(usagesJson), ", name=", *usageResult.Name)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Cannot marshal usages json")
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Cannot get usages")
    }
```

Output:

Quota result:

```
{
   "id":"/subscriptions/<MY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/providers/Microsoft.Network/locations/centralus/providers/Microsoft.Quota/quotas/VirtualNetworks",
   "name":"VirtualNetworks",
   "properties":{
      "isQuotaApplicable":false,
      "limit":{
         "limitObjectType":"LimitValue",
         "limitType":"Independent",
         "value":1000
      },
      "name":{
         "localizedValue":"Virtual Networks",
         "value":"VirtualNetworks"
      },
      "properties":{
         
      },
      "unit":"Count"
   },
   "type":"Microsoft.Quota/Quotas"
}
```

Usages result:

```
{
   "id":"/subscriptions/<MY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/providers/Microsoft.Network/locations/centralus/providers/Microsoft.Quota/usages/VirtualNetworks",
   "name":"VirtualNetworks",
   "properties":{
      "isQuotaApplicable":false,
      "name":{
         "localizedValue":"Virtual Networks",
         "value":"VirtualNetworks"
      },
      "properties":{
         
      },
      "unit":"Count",
      "usages":{
         
      }
   },
   "type":"Microsoft.Quota/Usages"
}
```

What's the correct way to get the usages value `3` exactly like when getting limits via Azure CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to get network usages/quotas using Azure SDK for Golang?

In my environment, Using the Azure CLI command I can get the **`usage result`** like the below:

[image]

To get the **`current value`** you need to use **`github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/network/armnetwork/v4`** package using Go lang.

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/network/armnetwork/v4"
)

func main() {
    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to obtain a credential: %v", err)
    }
    ctx := context.Background()
    clientFactory, err := armnetwork.NewClientFactory("your-subscription-id", cred, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to create client: %v", err)
    }
    pager := clientFactory.NewUsagesClient().NewListPager("centralus", nil)
    for pager.More() {
        page, err := pager.NextPage(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to advance page: %v", err)
        }

                    for _, usage := range page.UsagesListResult.Value {
            if usage.Name.LocalizedValue != nil && *usage.Name.LocalizedValue == "Virtual Networks" {
                log.Printf("Usage Name: %s, Current Value: %d, Limit: %d, Unit: %s",
                    *usage.Name.LocalizedValue, *usage.CurrentValue, *usage.Limit, *usage.Unit)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2023/10/11 13:07:54 Usage Name: Virtual Networks, Current Value: 14, Limit: 1000, Unit: Count
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Usages - List - REST API (Azure Virtual Networks) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/usages/list?tabs=Go#list-usages)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, @Venkatesan! Your approach has definitely resolved my issue, although it's quite interesting that the Query Service Client isn't functioning correctly in the Golang SDK.

I conducted some debugging and examined how other SDKs handle this. I was surprised to see where the quota value is located in the response when fetched using the SDK for Python.

This indicates that there might be a bug related to the Quota Service somewhere. I [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/pull/21735) with a quick fix proposal, which was subsequently replaced by a [bug report in the azure-rest-api-specs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/26170). So I'm hopeful that my initial approach (utilizing `armquota.Client`) will also function properly in the near future.